# Have 8.10 (ibex?) I made a 12.10 DVD, how do I install?

Tags: 12.10, 8.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I've got the 8.10 on an HP Probook, haven't really used it... I made a DVD at work of the 12.10, which I'd like to use on it instead...how do I install it?  It doesn't have an Internet connection.  I have nothing I need to save on the 8.10, so no worries about it in that regard.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to install Ubuntu 12.10, or is there a particular problem with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ubuntu's [official guide for installing the latest version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest). Now that you have the DVD, you will

- Insert it into the drive,
- Reboot the computer,
- Choose a different boot device (usually by pressing F12 during the initial startup; your computer should display a message about how to access the boot menu when it is booting),
- Select the DVD as the boot device,
- Follow the prompts to "Install Ubuntu by Itself"

It is far more likely that you will get a clean, working installation if you don't try to upgrade: instead, choose the option for a fresh installation that erases the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your data and settings backed-up, you should do a fresh install of Ubuntu **12.04.1 LTS** on your PC. There may be initial issues with drivers, but this should mostly be resolved by doing an update.

*This could be from a DVD or USB, whichever is easiest for you.*

Once you have **12.04 LTS** working, then try out (but do not immediately install) Ubuntu **12.10**. This should also work on your PC, but will in turn be replaced by **13.04** (in April 2013), etc.

---

I have successfully run **12.04.1 LTS** on an HP Mini netbook (Atom processor, 1GB RAM) or ex-corporate desktops (P4 2.8GHz, 1GB RAM).

*You are unlikely to be able to use all of the 'new' GUI elements of **12.04** (or **12.10**) with a laptop of that age, but it should work fine.*